# R telegram bot command

Tags: r, telegram-bot, r-telegram-bot

I've created a simple telegram bot using R `telegram.bot` package with the code below for the `/start` command. The issue is, when I type `/start` to this bot in a chat, it works just fine. However, when I use botfather to create a command for the bot, in this case for `/start`, it will invoke the command `/start@bot_name`. This theoretically should work fine since you are calling the specific bot, but somehow this doesn't run at all for my bot.

Essentially, running `/start` works and `/start@bot_name` does not work. Not sure why this is the case as from what I see from other bots both should work fine. Not really sure what other settings I should be turning on via botfather.

```
library(telegram.bot)

bot_token <- XXX
bot <- Bot(token = bot_token)
chat_id <- YYY

updater <- Updater(token = bot_token)

#start function
start <- function(bot, update){
  bot$sendMessage(chat_id = update$message$chat_id,
                  text = sprintf("Hello %s!", update$message$from$first_name))
}

start_handler <- CommandHandler("start", start)
updater <- updater + start_handler


# start bot
updater$start_polling()
```

Comment: You need to explain why you think this should work. It doesn't look like proper S3 code and if you have a `bot` function that behaves in an S4 manner then you need to should how it was created, --- from scratch. Hence my vote to close as not reproducible. My close vote can always be rescinded if you load the proper packages.

Comment: added a line above to load the right package. and it is definitely reproducible. obviously i wont put my bot token there. you have to replace XXX with your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. There is actually a parameter for it:

```
start_handler <- CommandHandler("start", start, username = "chatbotusername")
```

If you include the `username` parameter, it will listen for commands that includes the username as well, such as `/start@chatbotusername`.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.